# How to eliminate table repetition

Tags: oracle

I have a code like this

```
select a1.col1,
       a1.col2
from a1
inner join b2 b21
on (a1.col1 = b21.col1 and b21.col5 = 'some constant')
inner join b2 b22
on (a1.col2 = b22.col2 and b22.col5 = 'some other constant')
```

how do rewrite this code so i dont repeat the table b2 .
I want to use the table b2 only once as its a huge table

Comment: What indexes do you have on table `b2` ? And what on table `b1` ?

Comment: If there are indexes on `(col1, col5)` and on `(col2, col5)`, then your query will be faster than without indexes. And how big is the table? One thousand rows? One million rows? More?

Answer (score 2):

Can you explain the relationship between the tables?  In general, you cannot rewrite that query so that it uses the `B2` table only once.  But there are many cases where it could be rewritten if we can make some assumptions about the data.

If each row in `A1` maps to one row in `B2` for each constant, you could do something like

```
select a1.col1,
       a1.col2
from a1
inner join b2 b21
on (    a1.col1 = b21.col1 
    and b21.col5 IN( 'some constant', 'some other constant'))
```

But if `A1` maps to 2 rows in `B2` with a `COL5` of 'some constant' and 3 rows in `B2` with a `COL5` of 'some other constant', the original query would return 6 identical rows where this query would return only 5 identical rows.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by using **WITH** something on these lines (query not tested)

```
WITH onetab as (SELECT col1, col2 FROM b2 WHERE col5='c1' or col5='c2') 
SELECT a1.col1, a1.col2
FROM a1
inner join onetab on a1.col1 = onetab.col1 and a1.col2 = onetab.col2
```

Hope this gets you the desired result

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
select a1.col1,
       a1.col2
from a1, b2
where
    a1.col1 = b2.col1 
and a1.col2 = b2.col2 
and b2.col5 in ('some constant', 'some other constant')
```

Comment: This query will produce different results.